# How do I trigger a ReSharper LiveTemplate in the Visual Studio 2010 markup editor?

Tags: resharper

I created a LiveTemplate for a common HTML construct.  When I use a LiveTemplate for C#, it correctly detects when I type the beginning of the LiveTemplate name.

When I do this in the markup editor (i.e. the Source view for an ASPX file), I can't seem to get ReSharper to understand that I'm typing the name of a LiveTemplate.

How do I trigger a ReSharper LiveTemplate in the Visual Studio 2010 markup editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the entire snippet name and then press `Tab` (instead of Ctrl-Space)

See below a sample snippet I made and its usage.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Space works for me in an aspx file but not a razor (cshtml) file.

Comment: Is there no way to have it autocomplete while in, say, an HTML file?

Comment: Not that i know of however I just tested the above in a .html file and it also works; given most template names are short this works ok for me.

Comment: update: You can use Ctrl-E,L to bring up the available live templates.